# What is the correct way to pass dynamic parameter to the api call in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.SouName">
      {{ box.SouName }}
    </div>
    <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.Tame">
      {{ paint.Tame }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { test1 } from "./test1";
import { test2 } from "./test2";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      boxes: [],
      paints: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    test1().then((r) => {
      this.boxes = r.data;
    });
    test2().then((r) => {
      this.paints = r.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

**test1.js**

```html
import axios from "axios";

export const test1 = () => axios.get("http://35.162.202.237:3000/...name");
```

**test2.js**

```html
import axios from "axios";

export const test2 = async (SouName = "aaaa") =>
  await axios.get(
    "http://35.162.202.237:3000/pi?name=" + SouName
  );
```

If you see, in test2.js, i have **SouName = "a"** aathis means, i am checking the database name in a  static way. In the output also, it is showing as array[0] only, not an entire array which has **SouName**

**Note:-** I have an API call to get SouName as a response and then i want to pass this SouName to an API call to get SouName as a response.

And then i want to pass this SouName dynamically in test2.js.

As you can see, according to the output, in the paints , i have only one array, that is Array[1] not all like boxes array.???

Because of that reason, i want to changes to dynamic way, to pick the SouName directly from the api..

Can you please suggest code change, if there is any wrong Thanks

Comment: I tried cleaning up your question for you. If I misinterpreted your meaning, please correct it (or let me know and I can try again).

Comment: Why don't you declare a variable in your mounted method to pass as the value your function is requiring?

Comment: My only question is `from where this dynamic parameter came` ? Is there any other API call ?

Comment: @tryzord I added an answer as per the understanding of the question. Please let me know if that works as per your expectation or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question, what I understood is that you are making an API call to get `SourcName` as a response and then you want to pass this `SourcName` dynamically in `tabsandcontent` method ? If my understanding is correct, You can follow below steps **:**

1. In mounted() life cycle hook, First call the API to get the `SourcName`.
2. On success promise, call `tabsandcontent()` method and pass the `SourcName`.

**For Ex :**

```
mounted() {
  getSourcName().then((sourcName) => { // This API method is to get the sourcName value
    tabsandcontent(sourcName).then((r) => { // This API method is to pass the dynamic SourcName and get the response to bind in frontend.
      this.names = r.data
    }
  }
}
```

Edit as per the author actual code **:**

```
mounted() {
  test1().then((r) => {
    this.boxes = r.data;
    this.boxes.forEach((obj) => {
      test2(obj.SourceDatabaseName).then((r) => {
        r.data.forEach((item) => {
          this.paints.push(item);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```